How to disable dock keyboard shortcuts ctrl+alt+<number> in 22.04
When I type ctrl+alt+2 on Ubuntu 22.04, the dock opens the 2nd application in favorites. I am pretty sure it is the dock grabbing these keystrokes, as it displays a little "1" by the first app, "2" by the second, and so forth.
How do I turn this off? Google Docs uses ctrl+alt+ for paragraph styles, which I'd like to access.
Thanks.

I'd like to know the same thing but I don't have a dell-super-key package.
These cause problems for me because I'm used to hitting Super-0 to restore font size in web browsers---just muscle memory.
So now when I hit that by accident (I'd love to map it but can't) item 0 on the dock gets launched. I don't see a way to disable this.

Well, a reboot solved it, and the only significant change I made was to remove the dell-super-key package.
Per dpkg, dell-super-key "Disables the super key by default and changes the key bindings to CTRL-ALT."
So, I think that is the fix.
